Is there a way to get an ABI from a vyper `.vyi` file in titanoboa?
Let's say I have an interface file like this in vyper:
Filename: MyInterface.vyi
# pragma version ^0.4.0
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

"""
@title MyInterface
"""

@external
@view 
def decimals() -> uint8:
    ... 

Is there a way to get the ABI from this in titanoboa?

Looks like the answer is "not yet"
